# rails, incrementing counter not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, counter

i have the following

```
Tag.update_counters(Tag.where(:name => name).id, :count => 1)
```

im trying to increment a tag count, but the only thing i know about it is the word 'java' or 'ruby' from the value of name. however i have been unsuccessful in incrementing my counter. i tried doing increment and increment_counter but none seem to work. i also looked upon the cache counter but this association isnt a has_many and belongs to. instead this is a has_many: through association.

what am i doing wrong? is this a bad way of doing it?
thanks

UPDATE.

i fixed it by...

```
Tag.update_counters(Tag.where(:name => name).map(&:id), :count => 1)
```

can someone explain though why

```
Tag.where(:name => name).name
```

doesn't work?

```
Tag.where(:name => name)
```

returns a tag hash. and i thought by calling .name it gets the name attribute of that tag?

Comment: What is the result of running the above code? Error(s)? Silence?

Comment: it gives undefined method `id' but i dont get why. im supposed to be passing in an id parameter and i thought that after you find the tag with the correct name, you retrieve its id value

Comment: Omit the `.id` part. Just use `Tag.where(:name => name)`. This statement returns SET of record, not ONE records, so it's naturally you can't use `.id` on it.

Comment: i fixed it. i did..

Tag.update_counters(Tag.where(:name => name).map(&:id), :count => 1)

Comment: yes. may i ask you a question though?

Comment: Yah, feel free to ask. That's why I'm here! )

Comment: if you post the answer instead of writing it as a comment, i would love to select your answer as the selected answer = )

Comment: Did you try to delete the `.map(&:id)` part? It should work either. And if you are trying to fetch only one field from each record (and yor Rails is 3.2+) then use: `where(..).pluck(:name)` this way your SQL request will contain only `name` column in its `SELECT` part which is mush more efficient. Using `.map(&:name)` fetches all the records with all their fields and only then grabs `name` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tag.where(:name => name)` returns all the records with given `name`. Rails don't know before running this command if there is a lot of this kind of records: 1000, 1, or 0. So this statement returns ARRAY of records. If you want just one record then use: `Tag.where(:name => name).first` and the result will be ONE record from your DB so in this case you can call `.name` on it.

`update_counters` is smart enough to get all id's from every returned record. If you need to access to this records one-by-one you can do this like here:

```
Tag.where(:name => name).each do |tag|
  logger.info tag.name # now you can use .name as you are dealing with a single record
end
```